# Why does running a C++ program using Cmake takes so long each time compared to Java and Python?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

In Java and Python, once skeletons are built, future runs don't require such a long time. I am using CLion. Is there anything I am missing? I see the following message for every run and takes about 1 minute.
Thanks

```
Scanning dependencies of target adaboost_star_over_zdds
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/adaboost_star_over_zdds.dir/main.cc.o
[ 40%] Linking CXX executable adaboost_star_over_zdds.exe
[100%] Built target adaboost_star_over_zdds

Build finished
```

Comment: Do you modify anything in `main.cc` before "every run"? Or is your `CMakeLists.txt` file misconfigured?

Comment: Just adding a simple cout statement. Does a minor change like this in the whole code account for the long build each time?

Comment: If you change a source file, even if it's just adding, removing or changing a single character, means the whole source file needs to be rebuilt and the application relinked. That's one of the major negative points of compiled languages like C++. If you don't change anything the application doesn't need to be rebuilt, but CLion will still do some build-related steps when running (just to make sure).

Answer (score 2):

This is not "running" the program, this is "building" the program. And this takes a long time due to the include files that must be read, the pre-processor and the compiler make several passes over the code, then comes the assembler and finally the linker.

And if the build takes a long time for a single file as in your example, then you probably include something that makes heavy use of the pre-processor and/or template magic to generate a lot of code at compile time.

Comment: I know the difference between running and building. As I said, for each "run" this comes. I think what was said in the comments is the problem. I just add a single cout and it goes through the whole procedure of building each time I "run" the code. According to that comment there's no way out of this if I change the code a little bit.

Comment: It says "running the program" in the title of the question ...<br>
But anyway: Depends on the code and what makes the compilation taking so long. If you can extract this into a separate module that can be compiled once and then only linked/used without needing to change this every time, then changing the main program become faster.

Comment: "*makes heavy use of the pre-processor and/or template magic*"... i.e. C++ Boost Libraries :)

Comment: Yes @Rene, I am using g++ in command line along with Makefiles and separated my files and functions to speed up the process. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you're right and that was probably a cause. :) @squareskittles